# Need Help With a Simple C# Program!

Tags: c#

I Want to call a class into the Main method.. And I'm getting this error :s

Code:

```
using System;


namespace AddMinusDivideMultiply
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int i, j;

        public static void Main()
        {

            Console.Write("Please Enter The First Number  :");
            string temp = Console.ReadLine();
            i = Int32.Parse(temp);

            Console.Write("Please Enter The Second Number :");
            temp = Console.ReadLine();
            j = Int32.Parse(temp);

            Minuz.minus();  // Here its generating an Error - Error    1    The name 'Minuz' does not exist in the current context    


        }
    }

    class Terms
    {
        public static void Add()
        {
            int add;
            add = Program.i + Program.j;
            Console.WriteLine("The Addition Of The First and The Second Number is {0}", add);
        }

    class Minuz
    {
        public static void Minus()
        {
        int minus;
        minus = Program.i - Program.j;
        Console.WriteLine("The Subraction Of The First and The Second Number is {0}", minus);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Case matters in C#!

Call this:

```
Minuz.Minus();
```

Also, need to change your braces so it's not inside Terms:

```
class Terms
{
    public static void Add()
    {
        int add;
        add = Program.i + Program.j;
        Console.WriteLine("The Addition Of The First and The Second Number is {0}", add);
    }
}

class Minuz
{
    public static void Minus()
    {
    int minus;
    minus = Program.i - Program.j;
    Console.WriteLine("The Subraction Of The First and The Second Number is {0}", minus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `Class Minuz` is defined inside the `Class Terms` so it really is not defined in the context you are trying to use it.

You did not close the definition of `Terms` before declaring `Minuz`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the class `Minuz` is declared *inside* the class `Terms`, and it is `private`. This means that it is not visible from the Main method.

There are two possible ways to solve it:

- Make the class `Minuz` `internal` or `public` and chance the call to the `Minus` method to `Terms.Minuz.Minus()`
- Move the declaration of the class `Minuz` out from the `Terms` class so that it is instead declared in the namespace.

Also, as pointed out by others; mind the case of the method name. That will be your next problem once the class visibility has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have embedded the `Minuz` class inside the `Terms` class. If you make it `public class Minuz` you can call

```
Terms.Minuz.Minus();
```

to solve the error. But you probably want to move the Minuz class out of Terms.

Answer (score 0):

Unless its a typo, you're missing a closing bracket for the `Terms` class. The way its currently written in your post, you would need to put this statement in your `Main` method:

```
Terms.Minuz.Minus();
```